# Problem with Query Data in a Table

Tags: mysql

I have table `test` contain 4 fields

```
+----+-----------+--------------+-----+
| id | int_value | string_value | qid |
+----+-----------+--------------+-----+
|  1 |       111 | Red          |   1 |
|  2 |       111 | Green        |   2 |
|  3 |       111 | Blue         |   3 |
|  4 |       222 | Yellow       |   1 |
|  5 |       222 | Red          |   2 |
|  6 |       333 | Red          |   1 |
|  7 |       333 | Green        |   2 |
+----+-----------+--------------+-----+
```

I want to query `int_value` that match flowing constraints.

```
(qid = 1 and string_value = 'Red') and (qid = 2 and string_value = "Green")
```

The result could be `111` and `333`

It's not make sense if I apply this statement

```
select int_value from test 
where (qid = 1 and string_value = 'Red') 
and (qid = 2 and string_value = "Green")
```

Does one can help me? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a trick with COUNT:

```
SELECT int_value
FROM test
WHERE (
    (qid = 1 AND string_value = 'Red')  
    OR (qid = 2 AND string_value = 'Green')
)
GROUP BY int_value
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT qid, string_value) = 2
```

This is completely untested, though, so I'm not sure if even the syntax is correct. Basically it groups the results by the int_value, and finds any group where there's as many results as there are different cases. You need to have the numeric value in the `HAVING` clause match the number of `OR` alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than *constraint*, I think you mean *condition*. You need to use an `OR`, since there is no one row that can satisfy all `WHERE` conditions as you have written it:

```
select int_value 
from test  
where (qid = 1 and string_value = 'Red')  
    or (qid = 2 and string_value = "Green")
```

If you want the int_values satisfying both conditions, you can do this:

```
select int_value 
from test  
where (qid = 1 and string_value = 'Red')  
    or (qid = 2 and string_value = "Green")
group by int_value
having count(concat(distinct qid, string_value)) = 2
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the guy was getting at. The example was a bit bad, though... I think what he wants are the `int_values` for which both of those combinations exist.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not the cleanest method:

```
select T1.int_value
  from test T1
where exists ( select T2.int_value
                 from test T2
                where T2.int_value = T1.int_value
                  and T2.qid = 1 
                  and T2.string_value = 'Red'
             )
  and exists ( select T3.int_value
                 from test T3
                where T3.int_value = T1.int_value
                  and T3.qid = 2 
                  and T3.string_value = 'Green'
             )
```

Answer (score 1):

**Understanding the problem...**

Think about your query. If you take away the parenthesis (because all the conditions are 'and'), it would look like this:

```
select int_value from test 
where qid = 1 and string_value = 'Red'
and qid = 2 and string_value = "Green"
```

Furthermore, 'and' has the similar property of the multiplication: the order of the factors doesn't affact the result, so we can do the following:

```
select int_value from test 
where qid = 1 and qid = 2
 and string_value = "Green" and string_value = 'Red'
```

As you can see, it's **impossible** that a single record may a qid equals to 1 **and** 2; it's just illogical. The same thing for string_value.

**Simple answer**
So, the other solutions that use OR are correct (a qid record my be equal to 1 OR 2). To make your life easy, here is the short answer that also eliminates duplicates:

```
select distinct int_value from test 
where (qid = 1 and string_value = 'Red') 
or (qid = 2 and string_value = "Green")
```